# How can I have a specific route for / using Svelte and Svero?

Tags: routes, svelte

I am using [Svero](https://github.com/kazzkiq/svero) to do routing in Svelte. I have the following set up per the [Svero docs](https://github.com/kazzkiq/svero):

```html
<Router>
  <Route path="/" component={FrontPage} />
  <Route path="/pricing" component={Pricing} />
  <Route path="/about" component={About} />
  <Route path="/*" component={ErrorPage}>
</Router>
```

Note I do *not* wish to have / be the same route as errors (as shown in the docs)

This has the following side effects:

- Visits to / show the `FrontPage` content
- Visits to /pricing **show the `FrontPage` content** followed by the `Pricing` content
- Visits to /about **show the `FrontPage` content** followed by the `About` content
- Visits to / do not show anything

**How can I make a route specifically for / with content that does not show up on other routes**? How can I have a working fallback route?

Note I have tried `path="/$"` in case Svero supports RegExs, and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this is actually a [bug in Svero](https://github.com/kazzkiq/svero/issues/43). The config below includes a workaround:

```
<Router>
  <!-- See https://github.com/kazzkiq/svero/issues/43 /> -->
  <Route exact path="" fallback component={FrontPage} />
  <Route path="/about" component={About} />
  <Route path="*" component={ErrorPage} error={window.serverVars.error}/>
</Router>
```